# How data-role="page" height property will work on Samsung galaxy 10.1 tab?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Hi dudes I am new to Jquery mobile , I am developing Phone gap application using Jquery Mobile frame work. page theme not applying for total device height in samsung galaxy 10.1 tab. Please help me?

Comment: in browser it working fine but when I implement PhoneGap events in android it behaves as I mention above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5 in your development, you can check how your project will look on different phone and tablets, because there are with build-in emulators.
The Phone gap support is also build-in in CS5.5.
See [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/dreamweaver-mobile.html) for more details.

Comment: No I am using Eclipse and testing on tab not in emulator.